# MySQL union and order by help

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

The below code works but when i change Order by id  to Order by s.id, i get this error

> Unknown column 's.id' in 'order clause'

```
$construct =  "SELECT child.* FROM products child LEFT JOIN products parent on parent.name=child.parent INNER JOIN subscribe s ON (s.productid = parent.id) WHERE s.username='$logged' AND s.type='0'
        UNION
        SELECT child.* FROM products child LEFT JOIN products parent on parent.sid=child.sid INNER JOIN subscribe s ON (s.productid = parent.id) WHERE s.username='$logged' AND parent.keyword != child.name AND s.type='1'
        ORDER BY s.id DESC";
```

How can i change the code so it is ordered by s.id, which is the subscribe table's id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is trying to apply the ORDER BY to the UNION but the UNION only has the `child` columns (without the `child.` prefix at that), there is no `s.id` in the UNION. But you can add one:

```
SELECT child.*, s.id as sid ...
UNION
SELECT child.*, s.id as sid ...
ORDER BY sid DESC
```

You need to give it an alias as the UNION will strip off the table name or alias prefix. If there is an `sid` column in `child` then use something else as the alias for `s.id`.

Answer (score 0):

> "INNER JOIN subscribe s"

It looks like maybe you want:

```
INNER JOIN `subscribe` AS `s`
```

if that doesn't work, please post the output of:

```
DESCRIBE subscribe;
```