# Zendframework Union Issue

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have this code running

```
$sq = $this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from (array('cs' => 'code_statuses'), array('total' =>     'count(*)'))
            ->join (
                array ('c' => 'codes'), 'c.code_id = cs.code_id', 
                array ('human_state' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE c.state_id WHEN 3 THEN 'active' WHEN 5 THEN 'suspended' ELSE 'inactive' END"), 'c.*')
            )
            ->group('cs.code_id');
```

---

```
$sqtemp = $this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from (array('cs' => 'code_statuses'), array('total' => 'count(*)'))
            ->join (
                array ('c' => 'codes'), 'c.code_id = cs.code_id', 
                array ('human_state' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE     c.state_id WHEN 3 THEN 'active' WHEN 5 THEN 'suspended' ELSE 'inactive' END"), 'c.*')
            )
            ->group('cs.code_id');
```

---

```
if (!empty($options['state_id'])):
            if (is_array($options['state_id'])):
                $states = 'cs.state_id=' . implode(' OR cs.state_id=', $options['state_id']);
                $sq->where($states)
                                       ->having(total<=4);
                $sqtemp->where ('cs.state_id=5')
                                            ->having(total<4);
            else:
                $sq->where ('cs.state_id=?', $options['state_id']);
            endif;
```

The issue occurs when i try to use union

```
$sqfinal=$this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
                ->union(array($sq,$sqtemp))
                ->order('cs.code_id');
```

but individually `$sq` and `$sqtemp` work fine

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cs.code_id' in 'order clause'`

Not sure where I am going wrong

Any help will be appreciated

*edit

```
SELECT count(*) AS `total`, 
CASE c.state_id 
WHEN 3 THEN 'active' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'suspended' 
ELSE 'inactive' 
END AS `human_state`, `c`.* 
FROM `code_statuses` AS `cs` 
INNER JOIN `codes` AS `c` 
ON c.code_id = cs.code_id 
WHERE (cs.state_id=1 OR cs.state_id=2 OR cs.state_id=4) 
GROUP BY `cs`.`code_id` HAVING (total<=4) 
UNION 
SELECT count(*) AS `total`, 
CASE c.state_id 
WHEN 3 THEN 'active' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'suspended' 
ELSE 'inactive' 
END AS `human_state`, `c`.* 
FROM `code_statuses` AS `cs` 
INNER JOIN `codes` AS `c` 
ON c.code_id = cs.code_id 
WHERE (cs.state_id=5) 
GROUP BY `cs`.`code_id` 
HAVING (total<4)
```

The part before the union is $sq, the part afterwards is $sqtemp, the combination of the two gives the print out above
Both of them with union in is the whole thing

Comment: Which version of ZendFW are you using? what is the output of `(string) $sq` and `(string) $sqtemp` respectively? What is the output of `(string) <your union stmt` and lastly: try passing the `Zend_Db::SQL_UNION_ALL` constant, if you're using Zf1, which I suspect you are using

Comment: The zend version is 1.12.31
See above for edits with regards to $sq and $sqtemp

Comment: Union all gives me the same error

$sq=$this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
                    ->union(array( $sq, $sqtemp ),Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL)
     ->order('cs.code_id');

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.code' in 'order clause'

Comment: Just copy-paste the query in mysql (workbench, or some other tool you have, even cli will do), and break it up, find the syntax error. I'm no free debugger (I, like anybody else, hate debugging, but we all have to do it)

Comment: The raw SQL works fine in mysql
so I suspect it has something to do with zend framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a second look at your code, I suspect the `oder()` call on the union. You're ordering by `cs.code_id`, whic is not mentioned in any of the `select` statements, nor is the `c.code_id` for that matter.
Try adding either `c.code_id` or `cs.code_id` to the `SELECT`'t that make up the `UNION`, possibly consider using an alias, which you can then use in your `order` clause.

```
$sq = $this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('cs' => 'code_statuses'),
                   array(
                       'total'     => 'count(*)'
                       'cscodeids' => 'code_ids',
                   ));
//...
$union = $this->_codes->getAdapter()
              ->select()
              ->union(array($sq,$sqtemp))
              ->order('cscodeids');
```

This, I believe, should work. I've taken inspiration from various places. Here are some of the links that lead up to my answer (can't find all of them ATM):

- [MySQL union and order by help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278959/mysql-union-and-order-by-help)
- [Every derived table must have its own alias - error from combination descending MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119857/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-error-from-combination-descending)
- [Using union and order by clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql)
- [How to use union in zend db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181783/how-to-use-union-in-zend-db)
- [`Zend_Db` union issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4772): old bug report... contains some details

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at those documents
The $sq should have been 
$sqfinal=$this->_codes->getAdapter()->select()
                ->union(array($sq,$sqtemp))
                ->order('cs.code_id');
My apologies,

Comment: I found some code at the bottom of the page that was doing this
$sq->order('c.code ASC');
i commented it out, and my query worked perfectly, but it might have affects for other queries, will look into this
Thanks for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: @user2764582: You might try creating the `union` query manually, because, [as the manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), to use `ORDER BY` in the queries that make up the `UNION`, you have to use parentheses: `$sqfinal = '('.(string)$sq.') UNION ('.$sqtemp.')';`...